# how to share a datatable between two projects (VB.NET) using A Shared Variable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have created three projects. Project A,B,C. Project A Is a console application with The Datatable. Project B is the Class Library with A Public Shared Variable Called DtforC. Project C Is a windows form application with The Datagridview. Now I have added a reference of project b's dll to both project A and Project C. when project a is buliding up the columns i then equate the dtForC to the datatble of Project A like below

```
    Sub BuildTable()
    dtofprojectA.Colums.Add("Name",GEType(String))
    dtofprojectA.Colums.Add("ID", Gettype(Integer))
    DtofpojectA.Rows.Add("computer",0)
    dtforc=dtofprojectA
    End Sub
```

Below is the class code of project b

```
    Public Class Test
    Public Shared DtForc As New DataTable
    End Class
```

Now is the code of Project C

```
    Imports PROJECTC.Test
    sub Start() Handles me.load
    Datagridview1.Datasource=DtForC
    End Sub
```

but still nothing happens The datagridview is empty even if i add more records via the console application

Comment: `shared` does not mean shared between processes in windows - it means *shared*  between instances of the class in the same process! - That's why you probably want some service in between you communicate with ... it could even just be a database

Comment: A Database doesnt *have* to be part of the project.  Each project could open/use it on its own, if it is Access that means locating the file somewhere in `Users`.  Creating a DataTable is not so tricky that you need to have a DLL do it for you,

Answer (score 0):

.net 4 has got a class called memorymappedfile . Its pretty easy sharing data between different processes. Check the example in this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx